# Command 'ng' not found even after installing it using yarn global

Tags: command-line, package-management, environment-variables, 18.04, nodejs

I am trying to run an Angular project and to do that I have installed node, yarn and angular cli. After installing angular cli using command: `yarn global add @angular/cli` it said that success: `Installed "@angular/cli@1.7.4" with binaries: - ng`.

But when I am trying to create a project using `ng` it said `Command 'ng' not found`.

The output of `node -v`: `8.11.1`

`yarn -v`: `1.6.0`

My Ubuntu version is 18.04

Please help, I am very much new to Ubuntu.

The output of `yarn global bin`: `/home/amrinder/.yarn/bin`

Comment: what does `yarn global bin` output?

Comment: /home/amrinder/.yarn/bin

Answer (score 3):

According to [yarn cli](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/global),
your global package executables are in `~/.yarn/bin` location. You will need to add this path to your $PATH variable.
 Read [How to add a directory to the PATH?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-the-path) to see how to do that.

Or you need to reinstall using the command:

```
yarn global add @angular/cli --prefix /usr/local
```

which will install in `/usr/local/bin` which should already be in $PATH variable.

You can permanently set this in config as:

```
yarn config set prefix /usr/local
```

Comment: I have reinstall it and permanently set it in config as you said. Now the yarn global bin output is /usr/local/bin and it is still showing same error.

Comment: echo $PATH has `usr/local/bin`?

Comment: echo $PATH gives: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

Comment: yarn global dir output is : /home/amrinder/.config/yarn/global

How to change it to default?

Comment: are you able to see the package when you do `yarn global list`?

Comment: Yes. 
yarn global v1.6.0
info "@angular/cli@1.7.4" has binaries:
- ng

Comment: thats weird.. try with full path.. `/usr/local/bin/ng -v`